# Time series modelling: "train" function with method "nnet" is not giving satisfactory result

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I was trying to implement the use of `train` function in R using `nnet` as method on monthly consumption data. But the output (the predicted values) are all showing to be equal to some mean value.

I have data for 24 time points (each representing a month's data) and I have used first 20 for training and the rest 4 for testing the model. Here is my code:

```
 a<-read.csv("...",header=TRUE)
    tem<-a[,5]
    hum<-a[,4]
    con<- a[,3]
    require(quantmod) 
    require(nnet)
    require(caret)
    y<-con
    plot(con,type="l")
    dat <- data.frame( y, x1=tem, x2=hum)
    names(dat) <- c('y','x1','x2')
    #Fit model
    model <- train(y ~ x1+x2, 
                   dat[1:20,], 
                   method='nnet',
                   linout=TRUE, 
                   trace = FALSE)
    ps <- predict(model2, dat[21:24,])

plot(1:24,y,type="l",col = 2)
lines(1:24,c(y[1:20],ps), col=3,type="o")
legend(5, 70, c("y", "pred"), cex=1.5, fill=2:3)
```

Any suggestion on how can I approach this problem alternatively? Is there any way to use Neural Network more efficiently? Or is there any other better method for this?

Comment: Just for clarification, I have used `x1=tem` and `x2=hum`; temterature and humidity, respectively, as exogeneous variabls to explain the consumption data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be not enough data. 24 data points is quite low, for any machine learning problem. If the curve/shape/surface of the data is eg a simple sin wave, then 24 would be enough.
But for any more complex function, the more data the better. Can you accurately model eg sin^2 x * cos^0.3 x / sinh x with only 6 data points? No, because the available data does not capture enough detail.
If you can acquire daily data, use that instead.